# Manipulate browser and OS identification by Firefox?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, firefox

How can I view and change what browser and OS identity information that are sent by Firefox?

**NOTE** I've tagged both 10.10 and 11.04 because I want to know how to do so from both of the Ubuntu releases.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1441886/232606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, open the `about:config` page and search for `useragent`. You'll be presented with options to change the different parts that make up a user-agent string:

[image]

You can also use an extension like [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), which makes it easy to save a couple and switch between them.

Both of these methods work in Firefox 3.6 (10.10) and 4.0 (11.04).

Comment: Is this `useragent` thing the same as HTTP referrers?

Comment: By the way, edit the add on link to the English page.

Comment: Oops, thanks. :) No, the referrer is the page you came from, the user-agent is a string that identifies your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what can we do about HTTP referrers?

Comment: Unlike the screen shot in your answer, only two lines of `useragent` description appears for me. Even on Windows. But according to a third-party `useragent` reader, the info includes OS and other info. And is there anyway to keep the entire `useragent` streak blank/empty?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to *view* this data is to visit a website like [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) from within Firefox (or any other browser).

Answer (score 0):

We just need to somehow manipulate the user agent string of the browser in order to hide our identity. Various plugins are available in the market to do so.

- Just search for User-Agent Switcher Add-on on Firefox market in order to change it on your Firefox browser.
- Search for Random (Hide) User-Agent on Chrome for fixing the issue on Google Chrome.