# Make Firefox user agent appear as Windows?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to make Firefox or any other browser user agent appear like it would be Windows?

Because my online-banking refuses access due to my operating system. The only accepted OS is Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd imagine that they're just querying the user agent, which you can easily customize with an add-on like the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived).

Once you've installed that, Google can provide you with any number of Windows/Firefox user agent strings, and you can use the add-on to send the user agent of your choice when connecting to your banking site.

As an example, here's my user agent from Firefox on Windows 7.

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but still relevant in 2022. The introduction of [client hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Client_hints), which firefox has not (yet?) implemented, makes it slightly more complicated than just changing the user agent string.

**On Firefox**

You can try pasting the user-agent string (see below for an example) into a `string` variable you create yourself in `about:config` called `general.useragent.override`.  It can be, and sometimes is, all you need, but failure is also common.

**Use Edge/Chromium**

My current employer seems to have a filter which blocks any browser request that includes `linux` in the user agent and/or browser hints.  I can accept they "don't support linux", but did they also go out of their way to obstruct it or are that defaults from Microsoft?

Anyways to overcome this nonsense:

Whilst Edge is available for linux, whats the point?!  Edge, as far as I can make out is literally Chromium repackaged as a Microsoft release!

The following, including the command line options, are identical for both Chromium and Edge.

**Override the user-agent and hints**

- Start by getting into the console: 'Hamburger'->More Tools->Developer Tools, or right-click->Inspect
- Click the 'Console' tab and press 'Control+Shift+P' (is there a better way?)
- Type 'Network Conditions'
- Under 'User agent', uncheck 'Use browser default'
- From the selectbox choose 'Chrome-Windows' which currently resolves to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`
- Open 'User agent client hints' by clicking on the arrow there
- These may, or may not, be all filled out, but you need 3 brands, the platform, and version. The numbers will change over time.

  - Brand: 'Not A;Brand' '99'
  - Brand: 'Chromium' '107'
  - Brand: 'Google Chrome' '107'
  - Platform: 'Windows' '10.0'
- Press 'update'

Now it should think you are on windows!  Whoot!

**But only for that one tab, and that one time**

And it is very tedious doing that every time on every tab, so how to make it stick?

**Command Line Options**

Thanks to this impressive resource: [List of chromium command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

`chromium --durable-client-hints-cache --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"`

I have set that up as an alias so I can invoke it easily.  Works, so far, for Microsoft Teams and Outlook, Okta and others.

You can check what you look like at https://browerleaks.com/client-hints.

[image: Chromium Network Conditions to look like windows]

Comment: Thanks, your cli incantation worked for me and saved me from having to having fine tune stuff.