# google chrome web dynpro

Tags: google-chrome, google

How to solve this error message on Google chrome running on Ubuntu 14.04

"Sorry, your browser/program is not supported by Web Dynpro!"

but when i use firefox the site is working fine  (on Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

The list of supported browsers is defined in the Web DynPro runtime property file.  So for support for the browser you are using you need to ask the owner [SAP SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_SE) to include support.

You can however bypass this by editing your browser identification string (and make it look like it is a supported browser) with a [user agent switcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259921/make-firefox-user-agent-appear-as-windows).

Comment: thanks for the answer , so is this happening because of my browser or my OS

Comment: I had the same thing and switching to Firefox resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @Rinzwind:

- Install **[User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)**
- go to the site you are intesseted
- click on the icon added by the User-Agent Switcher and switch to *Windows Firefox 33*